# Converting 3D xarray dataset to dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, multidimensional-array, dataset, python-xarray

I have imported a xarray dataset like this and extracted the values at coordinates defined by zones from a csv file, and a time period defined by a date range (30 days of a (lon,lat) grid with some environmental values for every coordinates).

```
from xgrads import open_CtlDataset
ds_Snow = open_CtlDataset(path + 'file')
ds_Snow = ds_Snow.sel(lat = list(set(zones['lat'])), lon = list(set(zones['lon'])), 
time = period, method = 'nearest')
```

When i look for the information of ds_Snow, this is what I get :

```
Dimensions:  (lat: 12, lon: 12, time: 30)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-09-01 2000-09-02 ... 2000-09-30
  * lat      (lat) float32 3.414e+06 3.414e+06 3.414e+06 ... 3.414e+06 3.414e+06
  * lon      (lon) float32 6.873e+05 6.873e+05 6.873e+05 ... 6.873e+05 6.873e+05
Data variables:
    spre     (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 12, 12), meta=np.ndarray>
Attributes:
    title:    SnowModel
    undef:    -9999.0 type : <class 'xarray.core.dataset.Dataset'>
```

I would like to make it a dataframe, respecting the initial dimensions (time, lat, lon).
So I did this :

```
df_Snow = ds_Snow.to_dataframe()
```

But here are the dimensions of the dataframe :

```
print(df_Snow)
lat       lon        time            
3414108.0 687311.625 2000-09-01   0.0
                     2000-09-02   0.0
                     2000-09-03   0.0
                     2000-09-04   0.0
                     2000-09-05   0.0
...                               ...
                     2000-09-26   0.0
                     2000-09-27   0.0
                     2000-09-28   0.0
                     2000-09-29   0.0
                     2000-09-30   0.0

[4320 rows x 1 columns]
```

It looks like all the data just got put in a single column.
I have tried giving the dimensions orders as some documentation explained :

```
df_Snow = ds_Snow.to_dataframe(dim_order = ['time', 'lat', 'lon'])
```

But it does not change anything, and I can't seem to find an answer in forums or the documentation. I would like to know a way to keep the array configuration in the dataframe.

EDIT : I found a solution

Instead of converting the xarray, I chose to build my dataframe with pd.Series of each attributes like this :

```
ds_Snow = ds_Snow.sel(lat = list(set(station_list['lat_utm'])),lon = list(set(station_list['lon_utm'])), time = Ind_Run_ERA5_Land, method = 'nearest')
time = pd.Series(ds_Snow.coords["time"].values)
lon = pd.Series(ds_Snow.coords["lon"].values)
lat = pd.Series(ds_Snow.coords["lat"].values)
spre = pd.Series(ds_Snow['spre'].values[:,0,0])
frame = { 'spre': spre, 'time': time, 'lon' : lon,  'lat' : lat}
df_Snow = pd.DataFrame(frame)
```

Comment: Please don't add answers to your questions -- add an answer instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour. From [the docs](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.to_dataframe.html):

> The DataFrame is indexed by the Cartesian product of index coordinates (in the form of a [pandas.MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html#pandas.MultiIndex)). Other coordinates are included as columns in the DataFrame.

There is only one variable, `spre`, in the dataset. The other properties, the 'coordinates' have become the index. Since there were several coordinates (`lat`, `lon`, and `time`), the DataFrame has a hierarchical [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html).

You can either get the index data through tools like [`get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html) or, if you want to change how the DataFrame is indexed, you can use [`reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

Comment: Thank you for this information. Do you know a way to keep the index configuration in the dataframe from the original array dataset ?

Comment: @CElise I'm not sure I follow. Do you mean that you want the underlying NumPy array indices in the DataFrame?

Comment: As I said, i am working with xarray (not sure it's the same as numpy array ?), which I would like to put in a dataframe where, for each (lat,lon) coordinates, I will have a column of the 30 days of selected "spre" values (so indexing by lon and lat, then the time)). A df with 360 rows and 1 column. Sorry if that is not clear, my english can be limited in this subject.

Comment: you can reshape the data so that one or more of the dimensions appear in the columns with `df_Snow.spre.unstack('time')`. But pandas dataframes are inherrently 2D (or, really, 1D with variables/series represented as uniform type columns) - if you want to be able to maintain the lat, lon, and time coordinates as perpendicular dimensions I'm afraid you're going to have to stay in xarray :)

Comment: @CElise Honestly, I would not convert this data to a DataFrame. I think `xarray` already does what you need it to do. The idea behind it is basically to give you NumPy indexing (try indexing into `ds_Snow['spre']` (this is the `DataArray`, which is like a 3D NumPy array with Pandas-like indexing on each axis). But `xarray` is awesome because you can **also** use `lat`, `lon` and `time` to select data. It's perfect for your dataset. Spend a few minutes [on this tutorial](https://tutorial.xarray.dev/scipy-tutorial/00_overview.html) and I think it will start to make sense.